# Setting up PubSubHubbub (PUSH) with Wordpress

Tags: plugins, rss, feed

I'm trying to set up PubSubHubbub (PUSH) with WordPress so I can allow updates to be seen in real time, without refresh.   I have read many, many tutorials online on how to implement this plugin with WordPress but none have got it working for me yet. Here is what I have done so far:

1) I Downloaded the official PUSH plugin for WordPresss

2) I Created a Hub using Superfeedr with the following settings:

- Sub-domain: http://ianamador.superfeedr.com/
- Name of service: iantest
- URL / Service of service / application: http://caclord.com/buddy1/ (my test website)

3) I Added "http://ianamador.superfeedr.com/" under "Hubs" in my PubSubHubbub WordPress plugin settings.

At this point, I am unsure of what to do next in order to get this integrated with an RSS feed and allow automatic real time updates.  And I am also wondering if PUSH only works with RSS Feeds or if it could work with other content like blog posts within a loop aswell.

Here is my test website: http://caclord.com/buddy1

Here is the URL for my feed: http://caclord.com/buddy1/feed

*Any help would sincerly be appreciated guys! :)*